# There are $N$ boxes, each containing at most $r$ balls.

Tags: combinatorics

There are $N$ boxes, each containing at most $r$ balls. If the number of boxes containing at least $i$ balls is $N_i$ for $i=1,2,...,r$, then find the number of balls contained in these $N$ boxes.

I have solved the problem in the following manner:

It is given that $N_1$ is the number of boxes with at least $1$ ball and $N_2$ is the number of boxes with at least $2$ balls, then we can certainly conclude that the total number of boxes with exactly $1$ ball is $N_1-N_2$. Now ball contribution to the total number of balls by these $N_1-N_2$ boxes is equal to $1\times(N_1-N_2).$

Again, we have that $N_2$ is the number of boxes with at least $2$ balls and $N_3$ is the number of boxes with at least $3$ balls, then we can certainly conclude that the total number of boxes with exactly $2$ balls is $N_2-N_3$. Now ball contribution to the total number of balls by these $N_2-N_3$ boxes is equal to $2\times(N_2-N_3).$

Going on like this we can conclude that the total number of boxes having exactly $n$ balls is equal to $N_{n}-N_{n+1}$, $\forall$ $1\le n\le r-1$. Therefore ball contribution to the total number of balls by these $N_{n}-N_{n+1}$ boxes is equal to $n\times(N_{n}-N_{n+1})$.

Now the total number of boxes having at least $r$ balls is $N_r$. But, since we are provided with the constrain that each of the $N$ boxes contains at most $r$ balls, we can conclude that the total number of boxes having exactly $r$ balls is $N_r$, and ball contribution by these $N_r$ boxes is $r\times N_r$.

Therefore, total number of balls contained in these $N$ boxes is $$\sum_{i=1}^{r-1}(N_i-N_{i+1})i+rN_r=N_1+N_2+N_3+...+N_r.$$

Is this solution correct and rigorous enough?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the number of boxes containing exactly $1$ ball is $n_1$, the number containing exactly $2$ balls is $n_2$, and so on, up to the number of boxes containing exactly $r$ balls, $n_r$.  The total number of balls is then $n_1 + 2 n_2 + 3 n_3 + \dots + r n_r$.

Now notice that
$$\begin{align}
n_1+n_2+n_3+ \dots + n_r &= N_1 \\
n_2+n_3+ \dots + n_r &= N_2 \\
n_3+ \dots + n_r &= N_3 \\
&\vdots \\
n_r &= N_r
\end{align}$$
Adding these equations, we have
$$n_1 + 2 n_2 + 3 n_3 + \dots + r n_r = N_1+N_2+N_3 + \dots + N_r$$
so the total number of balls is $N_1+N_2+N_3 + \dots + N_r$.